# Trying to return integer with math.random, lua

Tags: math, random, lua, floating-point, integer

I made this code:

```
myHero = GetMyHero()

a = math.random()

function OnDraw()
    if (myHero.health < 2000) then
        DrawText(a, 30, 600, 200, 0xFFFF0000)
    end
end
```

`math.random()` is giving floats and I need an integer.  How can I get an integer?

---

**EDIT**:

As it turns out, `math.random(upper)` and `(x, y)` give integers.

Comment: Please do at least minimal research.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the Lua documentation. It is easy to read.

[Lua 5.2 Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html)

> `math.random ([m [, n]])`
>
> This function is an interface to the simple pseudo-random generator function rand provided by Standard C. (No guarantees can be given for its statistical properties.)
>
> When called without arguments, returns a uniform pseudo-random real number in the range [0,1). When called with an integer number m, math.random returns a uniform pseudo-random integer in the range [1, m]. When called with two integer numbers m and n, math.random returns a uniform pseudo-random integer in the range [m, n].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it returns a floating point number 0 =< x < 1, simply multiply it with one more than the max integer you want and round it down.